# Lubuntu 17.10 - display is very dark, even when brightness is at to max

Tags: lubuntu, 17.10, display, brightness, bios

I recently switched from Ubuntu to Lubuntu 17.10. I used Unbootin to create a startup flash drive and installed it over my previous OS (Lubuntu) on laptop hard drive (Dell D430). I remember booting up the first time had issues,like it boot up into a partition and didn't recognize it had an OS. I had to set the boot sequance in Bios menue to "previous" (the Bios menu seem to changed a bit after dealing with Unbootin installation). I'm pretty sure that after setting the Bios menu to "previous" (which got the computer to boot up to Lubuntu) the display changed. In the OS the display bar is set at max brightness, but the screen is still very dim. Please help.

Comment: One thing I would hope not is that this is not a hardware issue with the backlight in the laptop screen. What happens if you run xbacklight -set 100 in a terminal? That should set the backlight to max brightness. If for some reason no backlight is detected you would get the message `No outputs have backlight property`

Comment: If found what what wrong:

Comment: So is it finding it I don't know why the backlight is not increasing brightness. I am not quite sure what to do then.  if it was found that command should increase your backlight to max brightness.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason- Unbootin changed the bios menu and settings. Apparently there are now 2 relevant settings "brightness" and another one "ambient" which you can toggle on/off and also control the level of it. For some reason the ambient was toggle off and set to low level (aka dark display). Issue resolved.